# How to vertically AND left-align a cell with \makecell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, makecell

I am writing a table with the \makecell package, and I am able to left-align the makecell text with the command:

```
\makecell[l]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell}
```

I can also top-align the text with:

```
\makecell[t]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell}
```

Below is a minimum working example of my table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {lXX}
\hline
Head Col 1 & Head Col 2 & Head Col 3 \\
\hline
Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[l]{Long Data \\ Col 3} \\
Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[t]{Long Data \\ Col 3} \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I want to top-align AND left-align the text, something like:

```
 \makecell[t,l]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell}
```

How can I do this?

The best answer about \makecell, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281571/how-to-left-align-text-in-a-table-with-makecell/281575) doesn't address this.

Edit: left a package out of MWE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just don't add a comma between the alignment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {lXX}
\toprule
Head Col 1 & Head Col 2 & Head Col 3 \\
\hline
Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[l]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell} \\
\addlinespace
Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[tl]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell} \\
\addlinespace
Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[br]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. Will it work if I use [tl] or [lt], or does it need to be [vertical horizontal]?

Comment: Any order will be OK.