# Vertically align multi-line text in tabular with makecell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, line-breaking, makecell

I have a table with line-breaked cells (using `\makecell`) and want to align the content vertically. The ``makecell'' command has an optional parameter for that -- however, only horizontal, not vertical alignment works. I was following a question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410670/how-to-vertically-and-left-align-a-cell-with-makecell) (which, however, does not use the tabular environment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | m{8em} | m{10cm} } 
    \makecell[tr]{This should be \\right aligned} 
    &\makecell[tl]{This should be top left aligned}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:[image]

As one can see, the `t' parameter does not work for the right cell.

Comment: This is weird because I copied and pasted your code, and the right text is aligned correctly for me (top, left). If this is a MWE then maybe there is something else causing the error? I'm not sure.

Comment: Strange -- thanks for pointing this out. The issue seems to be with TexpadTex.